# I want to list the values instead of showing as options to select. Check the code below

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach

I want to present the data in options as list items not options to select. Anyone with an idea on the best way to represent the data as list of items i will appreciate

```
 <div class="attributes col-12 col-md-4 box">
                  <label class="">{{ $attributes_data['option']['name'] }}</label>
                  <div class="select-control">
                  <select name="{{ $attributes_data['option']['id'] }}" onChange="getQuantity()" class="currentstock form-control attributeid_<?=$index++?>" attributeid = "{{ $attributes_data['option']['id'] }}">
                    @if(!empty($result['cart']))
                      @php
                        $value_ids = array();
                        foreach($result['cart'][0]->attributes as $values){
                           $value_ids[] = $values->options_values_id;
                        }
                      @endphp
                        @foreach($attributes_data['values'] as $values_data)
                          @if(!empty($result['cart']))
                         <option @if(in_array($values_data['id'],$value_ids)) selected @endif attributes_value="{{ $values_data['products_attributes_id'] }}" value="{{ $values_data['id'] }}" prefix = '{{ $values_data['price_prefix'] }}'  value_price ="{{ $values_data['price']+0 }}" >{{ $values_data['value'] }}</option>
                          @endif
                        @endforeach
                      @else
                      
                        @foreach($attributes_data['values'] as $values_data)
                            <option @if($values_data['is_default']) selected @endif attributes_value="{{ $values_data['products_attributes_id'] }}" value="{{ $values_data['id'] }}" prefix = '{{ $values_data['price_prefix'] }}'  value_price ="{{ $values_data['price']+0 }}" >{{ $values_data['value'] }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </select>
                  </div> 
                </div>
```

Comment: You could use the Select with the multiple parameter. But you could use checkboxes as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can select `multiple` attribute in select. See example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp)

```
<select multiple name="{{ $attributes_data['option']['id'] }}" onChange="getQuantity()" class="currentstock form-control attributeid_<?=$index++?>" attributeid = "{{ $attributes_data['option']['id'] }}">
```

Or you can select a `<ul>` and handle the selections in javascript.